# Property decorator in S4 objects (R)

Tags: python, r, properties

In python one can use the `@property` decorator on a method of a class which allows it to be used as a property. So instead of `car.tyres()` you write `car.tyres`. Each time you access `car::tyres`, some method will run and return the value - according to the OO paradigm. In this way, you don't need to store any information in the object, but compute it on access (which allows a trade-off between memory and CPU time).

I am having now a similar S4 object in R and wonder whether

1. this is possible in R for S4 objects and
2. whether this is good practice in R?

As for (2) I have a feeling that a more common way to do this in R is to write a generic function `tyres()` and then do `tyres(car)`. But that doesn't seem as OO-programming to me. Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> As for (2) I have a feeling that a more common way to do this in R is to write a generic function `tyres()` and then do `tyres(car)`.

Absolutely. This is the natural way in R, and it has the advantage of exposing a uniform interface<sup>1</sup>.

> But that doesn't seem as OO-programming to me.

Why not? OOP isn’t about the syntax `object.method()`, although that’s a common perception (due to the commercial success of languages such as C++, C#, Java and Python that all follow this general syntax). In reality [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) is about data encapsulation and a loose set of principles to make objects talk to each other.

Different languages by necessity handle this differently. R6 very neatly imitates a Java-like syntax to object orientation and its usage might make sense in certain scenarios. But S3’s syntax is no less object oriented, and is more R-like: its syntax composes more readily with other R functions.

---

<sup>1</sup> Side-note: there’s currently a battle raging in the C++ standards committee about introducing an equivalence between the `foo.bar(baz)` and `bar(foo, baz)` syntaxes, under the moniker “uniform call syntax”.

Answer (score 1):

I never found a way to do this in S4. But this is certainly possible in R6 objects. It is called [Active binding](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/vignettes/Introduction.html#active-bindings).

R6 objects allow accessing attributes and calling member methods directly from the object instance with the `$`operator, similar to other OOP languages like Java and C++. This allows for much more natural OOP code in R than it is possible with S3 and S4 objects.

Comment: “[M]uch more natural OOP code” is a matter of debate (and wrong, in my view) because it’s *unnatural* in R. R, being a functional language, has a different view on OOP than languages such as Java and C++. Many people are first exposed to OOP via similar languages but they don’t have a monopoly on OOP. In fact, Java-style OOP has very little in common with the original OOP, which followed a much more functional paradigm.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, OK, I agree. OOP is about encapsulation, inheritance, polymorphism, ... and even S3 incorporates those. Not smart of me to confuse these concepts with specific syntax and my own preferences.